# How can I get the current location of an Apple TV device in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

I have the following code which runs yet always calls the didFailWithError delegate method. Is it even possible to get the location of an Apple TV device in tvOS?

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSLog(@"locationManager requestLocation");
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager requestLocation];

    return YES;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"locationManager didFailWithError %@", error);
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    NSLog(@"locationManager didUpdateLocations");
}
```

And the console shows:
 
locationManager didFailWithError Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

**EDIT:**
I also added NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to the .plist and added

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

in place of `[self.locationManager requestLocation]` above. I added the `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` delegate method and moved the call to `requestLocation` there. After doing this didChangeAuthorizationStatus was called with a status value of kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined and no permission request ever popped up asking for "Don't Allow" or "Allow" and the subsequent call to `requestLocation` still triggered `didFailWithError`. I tried deleting the app entirely from Apple TV thinking maybe this was a one time popup but `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` still did not do anything to prompt for permission.

I was finally able to successfully get the device location to work only after manually going into the Apple TV Settings - General - Privacy - Location Services and then finding my app and manually changing the setting from "Never" to "While Using the App". This is obviously not ideal and it would be better if `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` would actually prompt the user to choose.

Comment: For me, this worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738744/cllocationmanager-and-tvos-requestwheninuseauthorization-not-prompting

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724837/tvos-location-services-prompt-never-prompted/37496956#37496956

Answer (score 3):

Based solely on the posted code, you are not requesting authorization to use the location services prior to doing so.  You will need to call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` on your `CLLocationManager` instance.  It's also generally wise to call `authorizationStatus` and `locationServicesEnabled` prior to trying to use it.  You can [read more in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization).

Comment: I added an edit above to the original question with the results of adding requestWhenInUseAuthorization, moving the call to requestLocation and also adding NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to the .plist ... almost to a solution but not quite yet.

Comment: Sounds like the SDK isn't making it easy.  At least once you make the call to request auth you can manually go change it in the settings.  Have you tried deleting your app entirely and reinstalling it to see if it prompts the first time and you just missed it somehow?

Comment: I did try deleting it entirely and reinstalling but still no prompt. I can't remember if it did prompt me the very first time and I might have missed it.

Comment: @ScottNull did you ever get the prompt to come up?