# tvos Location Services prompt never prompted

Tags: location, cllocationmanager, tvos, location-services

Have anyone gotten CLLocationManager to prompt for permission on tvos? I'm using the following code (that works on other platforms) to get a user's location and prompt for permissions.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[self.locationManager requestLocation];
```

However, the authorization delegate is called with a status of `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`.

If I go into Settings > Privacy > Location Services > App Name, I can manually change permission and then getting a user's location works. However, I'm unable to prompt the user within the app. Has anyone else gotten this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my info.plist needed `CFBundleDisplayName` in order to show the location services prompt. Adding this enabled the ability to prompt the user.

Answer (score 0):

add to plist these rows with type bool and value YES

- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

then delete your app an if you using simulator go to debug tap then set test location

thats worked for me