# CLLocationManager and tvOS - RequestWhenInUseAuthorization() not prompting

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, tvos

I seem to be having a little trouble getting tvOS to prompt the user for location data authorization. I literally copied and pasted working code from iOS and it seems to not be prompting the user. I am using the code listed below as well as the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a string value. The only difference in the api that I see is on iOS it uses startupdatinglocation()  and on tvOS it uses requestLocation() (similar to watchOS)  I've stepped through the problem and it is infact hitting requestWhenInUseAuthorization() but simply doesn't prompt the user.

Any idea what is going on?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  locationManager.delegate = self
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

  if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined{
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse{
      locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that a CFBundleDisplayName key and $(PRODUCT_NAME)value is needed in order for the prompt to display.

Comment: Can you post an example in your own answer?

Comment: In my case, the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key was missing from my Info.plist file.

Comment: Adding `CFBundleDisplayName` helped, thanks! I wish they simply killed the app with an assert when something important is missing, rather than having us guess.